# Bash compare strings not working

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script for a homework and it is required to build a mini library with some functions. I got almost all functions working except the search function. The if statement in line 11 is always true. I don't know how to compare that.

```
$lib="library"

function search_book {
echo Enter Book Title
read title
exists=`grep "$title" $library | wc -l`
if (( $exists == 0 ))
    then
    echo "No Such Book in Library"
else
    act_owner=`awk -F, '/'$title'/ {print $3}' $library`
    echo $act_owner
    if (( $act_owner == $lib ))
        then
        echo Book Kept In $act_owner
    else
        echo Book Checked Out by $act_owner
    fi
fi 
stop=0
while (( $stop == 0 ))
do
    echo
    echo "=========================="
    echo "(t) Try again"
    echo "(b) Back to main menu"
    echo -n 'Choose Option to Continue'
  read reply
  case $reply in 
  "t") stop=1; search_book;;
  "b") stop=1; main_menu;;
  *) echo illegal choice, enter again:
  esac
done
}
```

Comment: Your first `if` is more simply written `if grep -q "$title" "$library"; then`. `grep` will succeed if a match is found and fail otherwise; there is no need to capture its output and test if it is zero-lenght.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `if` condition seems to be problem:

```
if (( $act_owner == $lib ))
```

Since `((` and `))` are used for arithmetic operations only and it is always evaluating to true because both operators get converted to numbers and if condition becomes `(( 0 == 0 ))` and **that always evaluates to true**.

Even this if condition:

```
(( 'abc' == 0 )) && date
```

will evaluate to true and print the date for the same reason.

**FIX:** Change that condition to:

```
if [[ $act_owner == $lib ]]
```

Comment: The condition `(( 'abc' == 0 ))` evaluates to false if before you set `abc=1`. Surprise. Bash's arithmetic `(( ))` doesn't always evaluate to true at all! but you're write that it is only for arithmetic.

Comment: Yes that is expected since `'abc' == 0` is evaluated as `$abc == 0` in `(( ))`